# Add comma separator to large numbers in risk table

Tags: r

How can I have the numbers in the risk table separated with a comma when they are grater then 1,000?

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
df <- data.frame(patient = seq(1,10000,1),
                 status = sample(0:1, 10000, replace = T),
                 sex = sample(0:1, 10000, replace = T),
                 time = runif(10000,0,5))

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df)
ggsurv <- ggsurvplot(fit, risk.table = TRUE, censor = F,
                     tables.theme = clean_theme())
ggsurv
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an option to add this within `ggsurvplot`, so you would need to hack the `ggsurv` object to change it:

```r
ggsurv$table$layers[[1]]$data$llabels <- 
  scales::comma(ggsurv$table$layers[[1]]$data$llabels)

ggsurv
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks!
did add 
ggsurv$table$layers[[1]]$data$llabels <- 
  scales::comma(ggsurv$table$layers[[1]]$data$llabels, accuracy = 1)
or because without it it added .0 to all numbers.