# How to change the decimal separator in a ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, plot, decimal, separator, survival

I would like to change the decimal separator of all the numbers (risk table, x and y axis, as well as p-value) in a Kaplan Meier curve from "." to "," (e.g. from 3.1415 to 3,1415). For the graph I use ggsurvplot from the survival package in R.

I found a post on here ([Add comma separator to large numbers in risk table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100887/add-comma-separator-to-large-numbers-in-risk-table)) describing how to add a ","-Separator for large numbers by changing the ggsurv object, but I don't know enough about this topic to modify it for my purpose.

Another post ([R decimal comma instead of decimal point in ggplot scales::percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66103544/r-decimal-comma-instead-of-decimal-point-in-ggplot-scalespercent)) I found was suggesting the usage of "geom_text", but this is not compatible with ggurvplot, only with ggplot as far as I know.

Is there any way how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100887/add-comma-separator-to-large-numbers-in-risk-table) you referenced already shows how this can be done. But instead of `scales::comma` you have to switch to the more general `scales::number` which allows to set the symbols used as `decimal.mark` and as `big.mark`. Also note that a `ggsurvplot` is simply a `list` where the `ggplot` is stored as an element named `plot`, i.e. to apply the second answer you reference you have to do something like `ggsurv$plot + geom_text(....)`.

Adapting the example and the answer by @AllanCameron to the more general case you could do:

```
ggsurv$table$layers[[1]]$data$llabels <-
  scales::number(ggsurv$table$layers[[1]]$data$llabels, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = ".", accuracy = .01)

ggsurv
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that has helped me understand ggsurvplot a bit better now. Apart from the risk table I also wanted to make these changes for the survival probabilty at the y axis, as well as the p value (not shown in the example plot). Do you know how I can access these in the ggsurvplot?

Comment: `+scale_y_continuous(label = function(x) format(x, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","))`